# How to create a mixed Scala and Java Maven Project?

Tags: java, scala, maven, intellij-idea, netbeans-8

I have googled aplenty, and I find scraps of info here and there, most old, and I haven't found a good answer.
I need to write scala and Java, and I'd like to do so inside the same maven project. I would like to use IntelliJ or Netbeans if that matters, with the latest Scala lib and Java 8.

What is the best way to create a maven project with Scala and Java code in it?

I've seen this but it's kind of old
[Maven: mixing Java and Scala in one project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33836905/maven-mixing-java-and-scala-in-one-project)

Comment: Does that solution no longer work?  Or are you just wondering if there is more "official" support for it now?

Comment: @puhlen I hoped to understand the most modern flexible way, given the current state of scala, IDEs etc. So the latter. Thanks